# Cleaning up and trying to consolidate an on edit code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

This has a lot of what I assume is redundant code. I While I am making my way to understanding more of how this works, I am a beginner at crafting these from piecemealing what I have read through to have this semi workable document here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqZNZX3zGRscG6teizjEFjmJMLKQmMLRCi6BmUL2T34/edit?usp=sharing

the Master sheet combines the other sheets into itself and automatically updates based off of the entries in the other tabs.

**Question 1:**

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r = s.getActiveCell();
var nextCell = r.offset(0,-1 );


 
//Movement SECTION
  if( s.getName() == "Movement" )  
    {
      if( r.getColumn() == 2 )   
      {nextCell.setValue("Spacing");}                        
    }
//Defense SECTION
  if( s.getName() == "Defensive" ) 
    {
      if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
        nextCell.setValue("Defense");}
    }
  
//Offense SECTION
  if( s.getName() == "Offensive" ) 
    {
      if( r.getColumn() == 2 )  
      {nextCell.setValue("Offense");}
    }

 //erases category if the exercise is blank
  if(s.getName() == "Movement" | s.getName() == "Defensive" | s.getName() == "Offensive") 
    {
      if( r.getColumn() == 2 )
        {if (r.isBlank() | r == "")
        {nextCell.clearContent()
        }
        }
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to combine all of these sections? the purpose is that on edit, the first column will reflect a category depending on the tab. I currently plan to have Column A locked and hidden, so it's less of an eyesore in the actual tab.

(Bonus Question: is there a way to automatically add the category to the query on the master sheet? [the cell is B4])

**Question 2:**
Is it faster to use protected ranges, or would it be better to implement a script to prevent changes to certain ranges and push a window to explain what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to go after your 'bonus points' question below, but first:

I use JSON in some of my functions like this to both simplify the logic and make it more readable.  Also, I switched the logic so it checks for a blank cell first so it doesn't unnecessarily perform a write before it deletes the content

```
function onEdit(e){
//checkAll(e) 
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r = s.getActiveCell();
var nextCell = r.offset(0,-1 );
var sheetname = s.getName();
var column = r.getColumn();

var check =
     {
       Movement: "Spacing",
       Defensive: "Defense",
       Offensive: "Offense" //if you add more sheets just add them here
     }


if(r.isBlank() && check[sheetname] && column == 2) { // !r.getValue() is not necessary, I believe.
    nextCell.clearContent()
} else if(check[sheetname] && column == 2) {
    nextCell.setValue(check[sheetname])    
}

}
```

Next, before the above will work you are going to have to get into your script and edit/isolate your onEdit(e) function.  At the moment it wraps around another function and then everything in the 'Location.gs' file is not wrapped inside a function at all and was throwing errors.  I didn't try to error check that part or figure out what it was doing.

Now, lastly, going after your 'for bonus points' question, a way that you can accomplish this that only uses google sheets, some duct tape and super glue, and no google scripts:

EDIT:

Okay, so I played around with an even easier way that doesn't involve any of the duct tape & super glue.  Simply replace the formula in your query with the following nested query:

```
=query({{query(Movement!B3:C,"select 'Space',B,C where B != ''")};{query(Defensive!B3:C,"select 'Defensive',B,C where B !=''")};{query(Offensive!B3:C,"select 'Offensive',B,C where B !=''")}},"select * where Col2 !=''")
```

This is short, simple, and doesn't involve having any hidden sheets at all and I think it's relatively easy to follow.  Performance wise this should be pretty zippy too.

---

THIS ANSWER BELOW WORKS (but isn't nearly as elegant)

1. Create a new sheet in this workbook and in column A from row 1 to row 100 (or however many rows you think you might have as a maximum), put "Offensive" in every row., in column B put "Defensive" in every row, and in column C, put "Space" in every row.  I've got an example here:  [copied example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/103MrLZRjiWADj28vrhU3VtvgrTYkH7BIHl-MzG92drk/edit?usp=sharing) in the 'Labels' sheet.
2. Next, in the cell where you have your query, put the following (for reference, the above sheet I called 'Labels':

```
=query({{array_constrain(Labels!A1:A100,counta(Movement!B3:B),1),filter(Movement!B3:C,Movement!B3:B<>"")};{array_constrain(Labels!B1:B100,counta(Offensive!B3:B),1),filter(Offensive!B3:C,Offensive!B3:B<>"")};{array_constrain(Labels!C1:C100,counta(Defensive!B3:B),1),filter(Defensive!B3:C,Defensive!B3:B<>"")}},"select *")
```

This should work for what you want to do without having to have a column for the sheet name.  The example in the sheet referenced above is a working example.

Comment: This was AMAZING!!! dramatically decreased the lag. I have the Location code to search for the first and last category entry and then use those values to make a "tick all box" at the beginning of each of the imported tabs.

I went back in and did some additional cleanup! I made it so that on open it deletes all excess rows on the edit tabs. ... but I don't understand checkboxes, so I can't figure out how to delete the rows in the master sheet that are empty save the checkboxes. 

would it be ideal to calculate the "rows" that should be in total, then insert checkboxes after somehow?

Comment: I don't know if making new script files helps, but I kept the location and code separate because there was a lot of indexing for terms and specific cells. new to the scripting thing so I just made variables for everything and then worked backwards for what I needed them for.

Comment: @KuukuuOmoi the best solution for the checkboxes that I have used is to go into the conditional formatting for the checkbox column with the formula `=$C4=""` and to set the text color to white, and in your case, set the conditional formatting to be for the `C4:C540` range (you could also likely do `C4:C`.  This is how you make one cell's conditions dependent on the value in another cell.  They are still there (although if you accidentally check one google will show a warning that an 'invisible checkbox was clicked' and ask you if it was intententional.

Comment: @KuukuuOmoi I went ahead and made the change on your spreadsheet -- since it appears as though you might be using the spreadsheet as your live version, I would suggest that you stop it from being editable, at the least, by people with the link but likely should have it be restricted.

Comment: @KuukuuOmoi also, would you mind accepting this answer?

Comment: I have been trying to accept the answers but I don't see any button to do so, and it won't let me uptick anything and record it yet.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really do appreciate this!!  I'll lock it for a minute and play around with the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is it:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const shts=["Movement","Defensive","Offensive"];
  const vals=["Spacing","Defense","Offense"]; 
  const idx=shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(idx!=-1 && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.getValue()!='') e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(vals[idx]);
  if(idx!=-1 && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.getValue()=='') e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue('');
}
```

Comment: that DEFINATELY cleaned up the entering of the category, but when I delete the cell or enter nothing in the space it no longer takes it away

Comment: So it needs some debugging.  I don't have your data.  Can you debug it?

Comment: I just added in the one i used before deleting it, I think it registers "entering" on an empty space and hitting "backspace/delete" differently, so having the | or situation catches both

Comment: still not erasing with delete, backspace, or enter on an empty cell